# Android Studio Virtual Device Emulator Not Functioning (Invisible) on Dell XPS 15 Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.5.3

I'm having some issue with Android Studio's Android Virtual Device (AVD) emulator.  I can build and run my apps but the emulator is never properly displayed, as I can't even see any emulated device at all.  I've tried different graphics drivers, different graphics (dedicated vs integrated), different Android devices, re-installed Android Studio and it's components, re-installed Intel HAXM multiple different ways, and still nothing.  I'd try a different version of Android Studio but I need this version for a class I'm taking this semester.  Anyone got any tips?
Device Info:

- Dell XPS 15 9550 Signature Edition; BIOS 1.13.1
- Windows 10 Educational 1909 Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363
- Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M GPU
- Toshiba NVMe THNSN5512GPU7 NV 512GB SSD
- 16 GB DDR4 RAM

Using Android Studio 3.5.3, Android Emulator 29.3.4, Android 9.0 and 10.0, and Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) version 7.5.4.

I can supply more troubleshooting info upon request but I left it out in the post as I think it scared people away from my question last time I included it.

Comment: What exactly does "never properly displayed" and "can't even see any emulated device" mean? Do you mean that the emulator windows do not appear? Do you mean that they appear but their content is garbled? Do you mean something else?